# Eigenvectors and matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

If A is a matrix of rank 1, show that any nonzero vector in the image of A is an eigenvector of A.

I feel like this is easy but I am stuck. I am stuck on figuring out the image of A.

Comment: Note that the rank of a matrix is the dimension of the image

Answer (score 2):

Note that the image of $A$ is one dimensional (since $A$ has rank $1$).  So, there is some vector $u$ such that $Av$ is always a (scalar) multiple of $u$ for any vector $v$.

Now, why is $u$ an eigenvector?

Comment: Because u is really kv where k is an eigenvalue, and thus Av = kv = u. So u is an eigenvector, correct?

Comment: @JimmyWalker sorry, you say "$u$ is really $kv$".  What is $v$ here?

Comment: v is the vector in Av

Comment: So you're defining $v$ in terms of $v$?  You're not being clear, so it is difficult to tell if you are correct.

Comment: At any rate, if you want to show that $u$ is an eigenvector, your goal is to show that $Au = ku$ for some scalar $k$.

Comment: So in my book, it says that a nonzero vector v is called an eigenvector of matrix A if Av = kv, where k is an eigenvalue. So if Av is a scalar multiple of u, then if we want to write u in terms of v, it would be kv.

Comment: Everything aside, I understand it now. Thank you.

Comment: That's only true if $v$ is an eigenvector of $A$, which is why you have to state which $v$ it is that you are talking about.  For every $v$, we can say that $Av$ is a multiple of $u$.  We **cannot** say that for every $v$, $v$ is an eigenvector.

Answer (score 0):

Since $dim(Im)=1$, $Im=<v>$, where $Im$ is the image of $A$ and $v$ is a nonzero vector.

Take $u \in Im$, $u=\alpha v$ with $\alpha \neq 0$. We know that $Au \in Im$, so $Au=\beta v$.

Therefore, $Au=\beta\alpha ^{-1}u$